# .Net Framework 4.0 SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, sdk

Does anyone know if there is an SDK for the .Net 4.0 framework, and if there is one, where does the installer put it on the hard drive?  I've installed the Ultimate Edition of Visual Studio 2010, but can't find the SDK anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last stand-alone version of the .NET SDK was 2.0.  It got integrated with the Windows SDK after that.  You already have the important bits on your machine, it is stored in c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windodws\v7.0a

It is a truncated version (thus the "a"), the full version is a [separate download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6B6C21D2-2006-4AFA-9702-529FA782D63B&displaylang=en).  Beware that this download is 7.1.  There have been a fair number of critical problems with the version 7.0 SDK installer btw.  The install failed on my machine, leaving a partial install that didn't rewind.  I had to patch registry entries by hand to recover.  I recommend you install this on a non-critical machine and just copy the folder.  I had no trouble with the SDK 7.1 installer.

Answer (score 3):

[Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 (ISO)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=35aeda01-421d-4ba5-b44b-543dc8c33a20&displaylang=en)

[Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 (Web)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b&displaylang=en)

These links point to the Version 7.1 of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A
```