# Signing algorithm used by .net 2.0 version of mage.exe

Tags: .net, vsto, clickonce

I have a VSTO document-level add-in. I develop it in one location, and deliver it to another. When I take it to the delivery site, I have to re-sign it, or else it will give me an error that the signature is invalid ([something like this](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2014/05/20/error-publishing-click-once-moving-from-net-3-5-to-4-5/) but I think the wording is slightly different). I don't have to do this at the location where I do development.

This wasn't always the case, it started at or around the time the network there started requiring TLS 1.2 and I switched over from building with .Net 4.0 to .Net 4.5+. .Net 4.5 is the first version with support for TLS 1.2. This kind of lines up with the codewrecks link above.

But, until very recently, I had to use an old version of mage.exe when I did this (the one in a folder named v7.0A, which [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566898/net-framework-4-0-sdk) is .Net 2.0). A newer version did not work (I tried mage from 4.6.1, although I did not try using the SHA256 algorithm when originally troubleshooting this as I didn't realize I could), and this is where I think it strays from that codewrecks link. If targeting .Net 4.5+ means it has to be signed with SHA256, doesn't that mean .Net 2.0 used SHA256? That doesn't sound right, even though it did exist at the time. SHA1 wasn't considered deprecated until 2011 and .Net 2.0 was released in 2006.

I can't actually tell what algorithm was used in .Net 2.0 because [the MSDN page does not say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-2.0/acz3y3te(v=vs.80)), and google isn't helping much either; .Net 4.5 onwards uses SHA1 by default, but supports SHA256 as well.

Earlier, I said 'until very recently', because I tried using mage from 4.6.1 again, and it now works. It kind of seems like the codewrecks link is the answer, and that it was fixed at some point in a newer version of .Net, but it still doesn't make sense that an old version of mage would use SHA256 and then later switch to using SHA1 as the default.

Is that the case?

Answer (score -1):

GUI saves your last choice, as shown in the image below.

[image]

You can specify the algorithm with 'update' command by using -a switch.

Comment: The version of mage that comes with .Net 2.0 does not have the -a switch.